# Trying to find a substring of awkwardly formatted string in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using ScraPy to get some information from a site and am getting a string back that looks like this:

```
[u'Oxfam-America Inc. \n            ']
```

What I need is to get just the "Oxfam-America Inc." part back.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> [u'Oxfam-America Inc. \n            '][0].strip()
u'Oxfam-America Inc.'
```

The method you want is `.strip()`. The problem is compounded because what you are getting back is a list, not a string, so you have to first access the 0th element in the list, then call the `.strip()` method on that string.

So for example if the variable assigned to the list you showed in the question were assigned to `field` you could print it with the following..

```
field = [u'Oxfam-America Inc. \n            ']
stripped_text = field[0].strip()
print stripped_text
```

Comment: This is a step in the right direction, but I need ONLY Oxfam-America Inc.

Comment: What about the u at the beginning?

Comment: That isn't part of the string.. that's just a notational device to let you know that the object is a unicode string.

Comment: Also, what does strip() do exactly?  It looks like it removes all returns and extra characters?